# Exclude subfolders with specific files in recursive rm -rf /folder/*

Tags: linux, bash

I wonder if it is possible to specify some elegant condition (parameter maybe?) in `rm -rf /folder/*` not to delete its subfolders, which contain files with name "dontshoot.txt".

I wasn't able to find any so far.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: to my knowledge `rm` cannot exclude patterns, you will have to write a function or script to do this.

Answer (score 7):

You could simply use `find` like this

```
find some_folder ! -name dontshoot.txt -delete
```

This will delete all files and folders recursively except the `dontshoot.txt` files.
As noted in the other comments it's always helpful to test it without deleting, which can simply be done like this.

```
find some_folder ! -name dontshoot.txt
```

However this will list all folders, even those which contain `dontshoot.txt` but they won't be deleted as they won't not empty when using `-delete`.

**Edit:**

I agree that fedorqui interpretation of the question is more reasonable than mine. To only delete folders that do not contain `dontshoot.txt` somewhere deep inside their tree structure a terrible inefficient solution would be

```
find some_folder -type d -exec \
   sh -c "find {} -name dontshoot.txt | grep -q '' || echo rm -fr {}" \;
```

**Explanation:**

The outer `find` command traverses recursively through `some_folder` finding all directories (`-type d`) and executing (`-exec`) the given shell command while replacing `{}` by the relative path to the found directory.

The `find` command inside the shell searches the found directories for `dontshoot.txt`. If it doesn't find anything there will be no output passed on to `grep -q ''`  which therefore will return `False` and the last part will be executed which will remove the full directory (which does certainly not contain `dontshoot.txt`) recursively.

In short, it traverses all directories and deletes those who don't contain `dontshoot.txt` somewhere inside them.

Comment: I have one doubt: what if we have a folder t/ with `dontshoot.txt` and `otherfile.txt`? I think your code would delete the `otherfile.txt`, although I guess it should not based on the OP.

Comment: Yes you're right, I extended the answer to your more reasonable interpretation of the question.

Comment: Congrats, this is such a great answer!

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to exclude them within `rm` command.

You can do something like this:

```
for dir in /folder/*
do
  echo $dir
  if [ ! -f "$dir/dontshoot.txt" ]; then
    rm -rf "$dir"
   fi
done
```

### Important:

Check it with `ls` instead of `rm` before executing.

Comment: I got upvoted and downvoted at the same time!

Comment: That's not me, I swear! ;D Thanks for reply, I'll check it.

Comment: @mr.nothing, always try your command with `ls` before using it with `rm`!

Comment: @fedorqui Probably the best solution. I tried to make something up with `find`, but I don't think this condition can be made up with it.

Comment: @fedorqui, I'm going to include this code to script. So no need to check it manually.

Comment: @fedorqui, doesn't work for me.. This code leaves top level dir but deletes that one, which contains file I need.

Comment: The problem with this solution is, that it won't work recursively. However the question doesn't make it clear if this is wanted or not.

Comment: Sorry @mr.nothing I had a typo in my code (variable names), can you check the updated answer? I checked it before and worked to me.

Answer (score 1):

The following function could work, I didn't have the time to test it, though.

```
// $1 = directory to remove
// $2 = exclude pattern
function rmx()
{
    rm -f $(find $1 * | grep -v $2)
}
```

Call like

```
rmx get/rid/of/this/ ".*?not-these-files.*?"
```

Maybe this can at least serve as an idea on one way to approach this problem...

Comment: `find` is the right way, but this way is to complicated, it's much easier to exclude the files in the search right away and use find's `-delete` flag. Check out my anwer for a full example.